# NSTextField won't setStringValue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I'm just at the beginning of a quite simple app (not really that into objective C yet) with a NSWindow containing a NSTextField. The appdelegate.h has this:

```
NSWindow *window;
NSTextField *userIDText;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *nextButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *userIDText;
```

the appdelegate is connected in Interface Builder to the window and the text field and then in the .m file:

```
@synthesize userIDText;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [userIDText setStringValue:@"user"];
    NSLog(@"UserIDTextString: %@", [userIDText stringValue]);
```

(I tried also other things than @"user" as string)
The log only shows (null) and the text field isn't changed. What am I doing wrong? I search the internets for about 5h now and it's obviously something really really simple I miss.

Comment: is your outlet set? set a breakpoint to make sure userIDText isn't nil

Comment: I did this before and wanted to just write "sure, as said I connected them in Interface Builder", but then I checked and it wasn't. Maybe I did something else wrong in the first place and then while trying to fix it I unset the outlets again.
Thx for hinting me in the correct direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method is called before the window is loaded. Thats why `NSLog(@"UserIDTextString: %@", [userIDText stringValue]);` prints null and you cant set value of the textfield. Try to use `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Assuming both the window and the instance of the application delegate that's receiving this `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` message are in the main nib file, if the app delegate is receiving the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` message, that means the nib file *must* already be loaded. In other words, `-awakeFromNib` is sent first, then `-applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, then `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Answer (score 1):

Just found your question as I had the same problem.
The issue was, that if you create a window with buttons and stuff in the precreated "MainMenu.xib", you don't connect everything to "File's Owner" but to the separately generated "App Delegate" object on the left side.

I'm pretty sure you have already fixed the issue.
Thought it might be helpful for someone else having the same problem.

Best regards!